# Delete #NUM Error Macro From Worksheet to Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run the below macro across my entire workbook of 117 sheets. I've tried a couple different variations of things I've found with research but with no success. I'm newer to VBA so I'm probably just missing something small.

```
Sub DelNUM()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsError(Range("B" & i)) Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DelNUM()
  Dim LR As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim sh As Worksheet

  For Each sh In Worksheets
    LR = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If IsError(sh.Range("B" & i)) Then sh.Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.